# Why is my second iframe not showing?

Tags: html, css, iframe

My second iframe is not showing, it is not even visible while inspecting element.

```css
@media only screen and (max-width: 480px) {
  #link1 {
    width: 50% !important;
    height: 50% !important;
    display: block !important;
  }
  #link2 {
    width: 50% !important;
    height: 50% !important;
    display: block !important;
  }
}
```

```html
<iframe id="link1" width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/31GYJE49ceY" frameborder="0" gesture="media" allowfullscreen></iframe>
<iframe id="link2" width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/HQysg8fQWvU?rel=0" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

Comment: Browser/Version? I can see both

Comment: Google Chrome in mobile view (iPhone 5)  version 62.0.3202.94 but I also can not see it in regular view

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/w6w0wuon/ Could you check here? I see "HOW TO MAKE 3D..." and "3D origami santa p.."

Comment: I see.. I have no idea why it is not showing for me could you maybe check at http://www.daniell.nu ? it should be visible when you scroll to the panda's and click the santa tutorial

Comment: @PaperLove You mean the Swan tutorial? The Santa one has a different video. The Swan one has the two you mentioned here. However, both videos are visible in iPhone emulation mode in Chrome.

Comment: Well looks like I put it in the wrong div, thanks for telling me

Comment: @PaperLove You mean everything is fine now?

Comment: Yes, I put the second iframe in another div and I didn't check that one because I expected it to be in the one that it is in now, stupid mistake

Comment: both are working fine https://jsfiddle.net/hry1kh13/